# Как элементу массива указателей присвоить значение другого указателя

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++

Давно не писал на c++, возникла такая проблема:

Есть массив указателей на объекты класса, допустим `Class1`.

Нужно отсортировать массив по возрастанию, при сортировке естественно приходиться переставлять элементы местами, т.е. одному указателю присваивать значение другого, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Делаю примерно следующее:

```
Class1* Array = new Class1[n];

Class1* temp = &Array[j+1];      // здесь все хорошо
Array[j+1] = &Array[j];          // а как быть тут?
Array[j] = temp;                 // и тут?
```

Во 2-ой и 3-ей строчке кода получается, что слева разименованный указатель, т.е. сам объект, а справа ссылка

Как собствено обратиться к левой части как к указателю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Вы завели не массив *указателей,* а массив *объектов,* отсюда и трудности. Вообще, вашу задачу можно решить двумя способами.
- Первый заключается в том, что вы начинаете честно хранить массивы указателей на объекты:

  ```
  Class1** array = new Class1*[n]; 
  // Лучше в таких случаях пользоваться 'std::vector<Class1*>',
  // а еще лучше - 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Class1>>'.
  // ...
  std::swap(array[0], array[1]);
  ```
- Второй заключается в том, что вы даете своим объектам семантику [`CopyConstructible`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/CopyConstructible.html) и тогда обмен происходит путем неявного копирования:

  ```
  CopyConstructibleClass1* array = new CopyConstructibleClass1[n];
  // ...
  std::swap(array[0], array[1]);
  ```

Answer (score 4):

[@Sergey041691](/users/5951/sergey041691), судя по комментариям Вас просто уводят от простейшего решения. Собственно, [@Котик](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) Вам сразу написал: "начинаете честно хранить массивы указателей на объекты".

Чтобы было понятней, посмотрите на чистый Си (g++ тоже воспринимает этот код как C++)

```
char *array_of_Cstrings[] = {"str1", "str2", "str3"}; // массив из 3-х указателей
char *t; // указатель

// обменяем первый и последний элементы массива
int   last = sizeof(array_of_Cstrings)/sizeof(array_of_Cstrings[0]) - 1;

t = array_of_Cstrings[0];
array_of_Cstrings[0] = array_of_Cstrings[last];
array_of_Cstrings[last] = t;
```

Вот и все, как видите очень просто.

Остальное придумано с 3-мя целями

1. позволить относительно просто создавать *проблемно-ориентированные* диалекты языка
2. помочь компилятору найти побольше возможных ошибок в них
3. поднять зарплату знатокам крестов (есть такая недобрая шутка)

Answer (score 3):

Так как тип "Class1" - тип, созданный  вами, то можно было бы его обернуть в какой-нибудь контейнер( или лучше даже адаптер контейнера ) STL( ну раз это C++ ). Лично я вам советую использовать адаптер контейнера `priority_queue<Class T>` и перегрузить для класса несколько операторов, **а именно: <, >, ==.** В таком случае вам даже сортировать ничего не придется - за вас это сделает контейнер.

---

Если по политическим соображениям адаптеры не нравятся, то можно использовать, например, контейнер `List<Class T>`. Перегрузив, опять же, при этом некоторые логические операторы. Затем отсортировать контейнер либо с помощью `алгоритма sort()`, либо же с помощью того же `sort()`, но уже на уровне самого контейнера `List`, если выбран он.

Comment: @Asen, а как это 
>>Перезагрузить несколько операторов
? Может "перегрузить"? :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! А все-таки, как-то же можно обратиться к Array[j] как к указателю?

Comment: @Rules, блин, неужели не понятно, что это была опечатка?

---
@Sergey041691, вам нравятся костыли и любите "геморройность" ? В вашем случае логично было бы обратиться за помощью к стандартной библиотеке шаблонов.

Comment: Я бы с радостью, только не умею пользоваться STL, не читал.

Comment: @Sergey041691, ничего, скоро поймете, как это сыграет вам на руку)

Answer (score 3):

Самый козырной метод - это использовать boost. В нём есть стандартные контейнеры для хранения указателей, совместимые с функцией sort.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
using namespace boost;

struct class1 { 
  int value; 
  class1(int v) : value(v) { } 
};

int main()
{
  ptr_vector<class1> arr;
  arr.push_back(new class1(5));
  arr.push_back(new class1(4));
  arr.push_back(new class1(3));
  arr.push_back(new class1(2));
  arr.push_back(new class1(1));

  sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 
    bind(&class1::value, _1) < bind(&class1::value, _2));

  for (auto el : arr) cout << el.value;
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```